# How to set OnClickListener in ViewPager

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I'm new to Android development and I'm studying to code & design an Android project. I have problem with `ViewPager` and can't find answer on this site or via a Google search.

**Problem**:
I can't make a `Button` execute its action while it's in `ViewPager`.

You can see my project & apk file here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9820517/ForOneTimeDownload/TestPagerView.rar

**Here is my PagerDemo.java**:

```
 public class PagerDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_demo);

        myPagerAdapter adapter = new myPagerAdapter();
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(2);

        SetAllBtnFunc();
    }

    public void SetAllBtnFunc() {
        //all func
        View.OnTouchListener touch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("hlv_trinh", "Button be Touched!");
                    return false;
                }
            };

            View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("hlv_trinh", "Button be Clicked!");
                }
            };

        //Get view
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.middle, null);

        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
        b.setOnClickListener(click);
        b.setOnTouchListener(touch);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_pager_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private class myPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.farleft;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.left;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.middle;
                break;
            case 3:
                resId = R.layout.right;
                break;
            case 4:
                resId = R.layout.farright;
                break;
            }

            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

**My layout content here:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Middle"
        android:textSize="30dp" >
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an easy solution.
In your layout XML, in the button tag, set `android:onClick="AnyName"`, then on your `PagerDemo.java`, place:

```
public void AnyName(View v) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

That sets `onClickListener` in a `ViewPager`.

Comment: **NOTE** for guys like me: it means REALLY do stuff you need, without those _findViewById_"s and _setOnClickListener_"s madness

Answer (score 2):

Although it is too late for this answer in 2021, I thought of sharing this as it seemed the easiest and the simplest one:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String[] imageUrls;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.loading))
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);

        container.addView(imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "One", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(position == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(position == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Three", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return imageView;
    }
```

Here, we just need to access the position of the `ImageView` from the instantiated `Adapter` item.

Answer (score 1):

i found something tricky solution for the view pager.As view pager is dont have any click event you can try click events on the child of the view pager.What i mean is to set the on Click listener on each page's root element.That will work surely.

Answer (score 1):

I did this problem as follows

You must first implement the **ClickableViewPager**

```
package ai.units;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class ClickableViewPager extends ViewPager {

  private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

  public ClickableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
  }

  public ClickableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
  }

  private void setup() {
    final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new    GestureDetector(getContext(), new TapGestureListener());

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
  }

  public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
  }

  private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
      if(mOnItemClickListener != null) {
        mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(getCurrentItem());
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

and then in xml like this

```
  <ai.units.ClickableViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You can now use the *setOnItemClickListener* method

```
viewPager.setOnItemClickListener(new ClickableViewPager.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(int position) {
       Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: position = "+position);
     }
   });
```

**NOTE**

***ai.units.*** The name of my package is and you have to move it with your own package

[The main link of the answer that has been take from there](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/48491/viewpager-onitemclicklistener)

Answer (score 0):

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int Position) {
            position=Position;
        }
 });
```

You will use any view for clicking without `viewpager` and go to details by using the selected position of viewpager

Answer (score 0):

**View Pager click to event position**
*Like your side 3 fragment and click position event different different API or any call method then used my code.*

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerTab);
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

TabViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(HomeFragment.newInstance(), null, "Home", 0);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(LiveCallsFragment.newInstance(), null, "Live Calls", 1);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFrag(CallDetailsFragment.newInstance(), null, "Call Details", 2);


viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 2){
                chePassWordApi();
               // Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, " Rahul call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0){
                chePassWordApi();
               // Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, " Rahul Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (position == 1){
                chePassWordApi();
               // Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Rahul Live", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```