# how to set a android view pager clickable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set OnClickListener in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490604/how-to-set-onclicklistener-in-viewpager)

I am using android 2.2 .I want to go another activity after clicking an image within viewpager.Can any one help me?Is there any method for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a ViewPager is to flip/swipe horizontally through views (typically fragments). You should clarify what you are hoping to achieve with setting it clickable. If you want a navigation take a look at [VPI](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)